# Internet Explorer showing alert value "undefine" but Firefox and chrome showing actual value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing problem in Internet Explorer, the following code is running fine on both Firefox and Chrome, but Internet Explorer showing alert value "undefine"

```
var yearId = $('#planService tbody tr td select#recognizeType').val();
alert(yearId);
$('#recogTypeId').val(yearId);
```

any update ?

Comment: Can we see the HTML within `#planService`?  Also, which version of IE?  Old versions have all sorts of issues.

Comment: @MikeChristensen yes! and I am using internet explorer 11

Comment: Making a simple fiddle, guessing on your HTML, it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/x2ah266n/  
However, I should note, that if select has a unique ID, as the definition of ID requires, you do not need all of the other selector text.  You can simply use `$('#recognizeType').val()`

Comment: @JeffB because there are many recognizeType relating to area.I required `#planService tbody tr td select#recognizeType` that comes under planService

Comment: By definition, you cannot have more than one ID with the same name.  Use a class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE gets crazy when elements with the same ids gets in the way!

Answer (score 1):

It may be an IE issue, but since #recognizeType is an ID why not just use:

```
var yearID = $('#recognizeType').val();
```

Comment: because there are many recognizeType relating to area.I required `#planService tbody tr td select#recognizeType` that comes under planService :)

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor You can't use an ID more than once. That might be your problem.

Comment: IE gets crazy when elements with the same ids gets in the way

Comment: You may want to try removing the "tbody tr" and see what happens, are they really necessary?